# Can wish be used to recharge magic weapons, armor, or items that use charges?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wish

Wish explicitly states that it cannot be used to create magic items, however, it doesn't say anything about using the wish to recharge a magic item (if it uses the charges system). Is it with the bounds of the spell to accomplish this or would it be up to the DM?

Comment: The wish spell actually says you CAN wish for a magic item, but that could lead you to being transported to the footsteps of the current and quite possibly deadly owner of said magic item. Remember that it's also your DM's discretion. Maybe he DOES allow the magic item to be recharged, but to do this, he takes your character back in time to a point where the weapon WAS charged. The wish spell is just as dangerous as it is wondrous, so be weary when using it for any purposes other than it's already described uses.

Answer (score 4):

## DM decides

Wish says:

> You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above examples. State your wish to the DM as precisely as possible. The DM has great latitude in ruling what occurs... This spell might simply fail

Since recharging magic item charges is not within the scope of the spell, it is entirely up to the DM. This is unrelated to creating magic items, so there is no RAW that says it can't.

Answer (score 4):

I'd communicate with your DM regarding the specific use of the wish spell to recharge your item. For example, the **Luck Blade**:

> **Luck Blade**
>
> *Weapon (any sword), legendary (requires attunement)*
>
> You gain a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic
> weapon. While the sword is on your person, you also gain a +1 bonus to
> saving throws.
>
> **Luck**. If the sword is on your person, you can call on its luck (no
> action required) to reroll one attack roll, ability check, or saving
> throw you dislike. You must use the second roll. This property can’t
> be used again until the next dawn.
>
> **Wish**. The sword has 1d4-1 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 charge and cast the Wish spell from it. This
> property can’t be used again until the next dawn. The sword loses this
> property if it has no charges.

If you were trying to recharge this item, then I'd imagine you'd be out of luck

Comment: Was that a pun I see at the end?